# What is the order that things are happening?

Tags: go

I started playing around with Go by going through the Tour of Go on the official site.

I only have basic experience with programming but on coming up to the channels page I started to play around to try get my head around it and I've ended up quite confused.

This is what I have the code as:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    s[0] = 8
    s = append(s, 20)
    fmt.Println(s)
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
    fmt.Println(s[0])
    go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
    fmt.Println(s)
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

And this is the result I get:

```
7
[8 2 8 20 4 0]
[8 2 8 20]
[8 4 0 20]
26 32 58
[8 2 8 8 4 0]
```

I get that in creating a slice you get an underlying array with needed number underneath and passes a slice to a function and modifying an element modifying the underlying array but I'm not sure in what sort of order the goroutines are going.

It prints out the first S[0] as 7 even though the function call before it should have modified it to 8, so I'm assuming that the goroutines hasn't run yet?
Then printing the entire array after the second goroutine function call prints it with all the modifications made during the first function call (modifying the first item to 8 and appending 20).
Yet the next 2 line print outs are the print outs of the slice segments from within the functions, which logically by the fact that I just said I saw the modifications done by the function call means they should have printed out BEFORE that line.

Then I'm not sure how it got the calculations or the final printout of the array.

Can someone familiar with how Go operates explain what the logical progression of this code was?

Comment: In the first call to sum(), you are passing a new array (result of a slice), so sum() doesn't have a reference to the original array and therefore can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

> It prints out the first S[0] as 7 even though the function call before it should have modified it to 8, so I'm assuming that the goroutines hasn't run yet?

Yes, this interpretation is correct. (But should *not* be made, see next section).

> Then printing the entire array after the second goroutine function call prints it with all the modifications made during the first function call (modifying the first item to 8 and appending 20).

NO. Never ever think along these lines.
The state of your application at this point is *not* well defined. 1) You started goroutines which modify the state and you have *absolutely* *no* synchronisation between the three goroutines (the main one and the two you started manually). 2) Your code is racy which means it is a) wrong, racy programs are *never* correct and b) results in undefined behaviour.

> Yet the next 2 line print outs are the print outs of the slice segments from within the functions, which logically by the fact that I just said I saw the modifications done by the function call means they should have printed out BEFORE that line.

More or less, if your program would not be racy (see above).

Where is your code racy: the `main.s` is a slice with a backing array and you subslice it twice when starting the goroutines with `go sum(...)`. Both subslices share the *same* backing array. Now inside the goroutines you write ( `s[0]=8`) and append (`append(s, 20)`) to this subslice. From both goroutines without synchronisation. The first goroutine will fulfill this append using the large enough backing array which is concurrently used by the second goroutine.
This results in concurrent write without synchronisation to the fourth element of `main.s` which is racy and thus undefined.

With reading twice from the channel (`<-c, <-c`) you introduce synchronisation between the two manually started goroutines and the main goroutine and your program returns to serial execution (but its state is still not welldefined as it is racy).
The Println statements you use to track what is going on are problematic too: These statements print stuff which is in a not well defined state because it is accessed concurrently from different goroutines; both may print arbitrary data.

Summing up: You program is racy, its output is undefined, there is no "reason" or "explanation" why it prints what it prints, its pure chance.
Always try your code under the race detector (-race) and do not try to make up pseudo-explanations for racy code.

How to fix: 
The divide and conquer approach is nice and okay. What is dangerous and thus easy to get wrong (as it happened to you) is modifying the subslice inside the goroutine. While `s[0]=9`] is harmless in your case the append interferes badly with the shared backing array.
Do not modify s inside the goroutine. If you must: Make sure you have a new backing array.

(Do not try to mix slices and concurrency. Both have some subtleties, slices the shared backing array and concurrency the problem of undefined racy behaviour. Especially if you are new to all this. Learn one, then the other, then combine both.)

Comment: Hmmm, most of this code is from the Tour of Go on the official site trying to explain hot to write goroutines and channels, some of the extra code is just me trying to get my head around how it is working.
Looks like its time for me to spend more time reading about multi threading fundamentals.

Comment: @Mowen The part from the Tour is not the problem. The problem are your modifications which _introduce_ races rendering the Tour's code invalid.